# Implementar paypal con php

Tags: php, paypal

estoy implementando paypal in mi página web, el problema que tengo es que primero lo estoy haciendo a través de sand box ya que estoy haciendo pruebas con las dos cuentas (business y personal) ficticias.
El pago me lo hace bien pero yo he activado IPN para recibir la información y saber si está pagado o no y así poder actualizarlo en mi base de datos. Está todo activado y llega a la página web que le he indicado de IPN. 
El problema es que no me acaba de funcionar. Además, todos los pagos tienen su estado en se está revisando y no sé si a lo mejor está aquí el problema. Pongo aquí el código

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// If testing on Sandbox use:
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443\r\n";
// For live servers use $header .= "Host: www.paypal.com:443\r\n";

// Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
// If testing on Sandbox use:
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
// For live servers use $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

fputs($fp, $header . $req);
$id_reserva=$_POST['item_number'];

while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets($fp, 1024);
        $sql="update reservas set estado='".$id_reserva."'";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {  
            $sql="update reservas set estado='1'";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) { 
            $sql="update reservas set estado='2'";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
        fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Dentro del while si que me entra ya que esa consulta si me la hace bien: 
$sql="update reservas set estado='".$id_reserva."'";

pero no me entra en ningún de los 2 if que hay, entonces no puedo validar si se ha pagado correctamente o no.

Comment: No hay nadie que me pueda ayudar??

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene `$res` a la hora de comparar? Y no relacionado, ¿por qué un `update` sin un  `where`? eso te va a actualizar todos los registros de la tabla y no sólo el de la reserva que acabas de hacer

Comment: El update solo era para probar que me llegaba hasta allí, he hecho una tabla de prueba con dos registros sólo para probar que al menos llegaba a la consulta. Al final he podido resolverlo, gracias igualmente!